# How to assemble the U.S. Green Card Application

Tags: usa, greencard

I'm new to the law Stack Exchange. I'm writing with a question on filing and assembling a U.S. green card application for USCIS.

My husband and I are filing an Adjustment of Status application (for the green card), have done the paper work, and have procured the evidence/documents needed! We would just like to know:

What is the best way of physically *organizing and assembling* the entire packet. Do you suggest placing the individual forms with their accompanying evidence in separate envelopes? Or, assembling one stack of forms atop an indexed stack of evidence?

Any pointers on how to assemble and organize the green card packet for the USCIS, given the many forms and copies, would be greatly appreciated. An advanced thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a legal question but asking advice about a bureaucratic process.

Comment: Call or email USCIS and ask.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly suitable for Expatriates, and should be left open. The task faced by the OP is faced only by an expatriate.

Answer (score 1):

General guideline are:

Write a cover letter for each form (I-130, E-485, I-864, I-765) with applicant and sponsor information and list all the documentation (as a bullet point list) that you are attaching.

Write another "main" cover letter with applicant and sponsor information and list all forms attached.

For the evidence of *Bona Fide* marriage, create a table of contents and organize documents by categories (Bills, Bank Statements, Pictures, Affidavits, etc).

Is recommended that all documentation must printed on standard 8 1/2 by 11 size. If you decide to add tabs for easier navigation do it at the bottom of the page **not on the side!** You can use post-it to do this.

Bind everything together using clips **not staples!** USCIS keep their paperwork organized by clips on the top of the page. Similar to [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71HvtU9GKkL._AC_SY355_.jpg).

Add the passport pictures on a ziploc bag followed by your notification and money form on the very top of the package.

Finally, don't forget to sign all forms before submitting.

https://www.uscis.gov/forms/forms-information/form-filing-tips

Comment: Thank you so much, IanDan! That is incredibly helpful, especially the point about the Cover Letters. I will also assume that passport photos only need to provided once (even though they are asked for multiple times in the application). I've heard it's ok to place the set of photos on top.

Comment: @DrStockinette I forgot about the pictures! Thanks for reminding me. Yes, place them in a ziploc bag up on top. I would do 4 of each person just to be safe. Also, you can do DIY passport pictures to save some money if you feel comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should put all evidence and forms altogether in one envelope so that they have all the appropriate forms in one stack when they file your applications.